# How to create button like 

Tags: objective-c, xcode, button, interface-builder, nsbutton

... this

[image]

what should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Photoshop (or whatever you use) and add those images to custom button.

You could visit sites such as http://www.iconfinder.com and search for 'Play', 'Next', 'Back' and so on. There are a lot of buttons without need for you to make them. Then just add them to your project and use the 'custom button' type in interfacebuilder/code.